# What kind of mushroom is this?

Tags: identification, mushrooms

I found this in my garden:[image]
What type of mushroom is it? What is that ink-like substance? Does it affect in some way to the other plants?

Comment: Welcome to the site! We generally don't answer questions about safety of eating a mushroom or plant. However, if you change the question just to ask which mushroom it is, we'd be happy to try and help with that. As you can see, @pnuts gave you a link to compare your mushroom for identification purposes. Other people might also do that. Since you're new here, have a look at our [help] to learn about our site. Leave a note here if you'd like us to re-word the question or explain further. We hope you stay and have some fun!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from the comments whether or not you've found the answer to your question, but this is one of the Coprinopsis mushrooms or toadstools, commonly known as Inkcap. They start out bellshaped, then flatten out over time, and the spore print is black - as it deteriorates, it can exude black liquid, which once was used as ink. It's a saprophytic mushroom, meaning it lives on dead matter, and will not be harmful to other plants. Info here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprinopsis_atramentaria

Comment: Close, but not exact. It's C. comatus, not atramentaria. (Sorry, sudden bout of know-it-all-ness ;-))

Comment: @Stephie - oh dear, well obviously the link was misleading - I only put in the link as general info on Coprinopsis  or inkcaps in general rather than atramentaria in particular, so yea, you're right - most excrete inky black stuff over time